# Log4j 2 automatic marker selection

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I need to log a message with two different markers depending on the information I get to log in.
For example i've this pattern:

```
ts: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} | logLevel: %-5level | appId: example-app-id | thread: (%t) | SID: %X{SID} | TN: %X{TN} | clientIp: %X{clientIp} | username: %X{user} | apiType: B2B | api: %X{api} | platform: %X{platform} | %m%n
```

but i want that this pattern log only if username and api aren't null or empty. 
Otherwise, i want to log with this pattern:

```
ts: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} | logLevel: %-5level | appId: example-app-id | thread: (%t) | SID: %X{SID} | TN: %X{TN} | %m%n
```

How to do this choice without impact the code by checking everytime those informations?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the %equals pattern, in fact the [log4j2 manual Pattern page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) has an example that tells you how to do exactly what you need.

In your specific case you would replace:

`| username: %X{user} | apiType: B2B | api: %X{api}`

With this:

`%equals{| username: %X{user}}{| username: }{} | apiType: B2B %equals{| api: %X{api}}{| api: }{}`